# Mitsubishi Lancer active 2012 body kit query

Tags: mitsubishi, body, lancer

I have a 2012 Mitsubishi Lancer active which I have found to be quite uncommon however I don’t like the way the bottom of the from number tilts back inside so I was wondering if any of the Mitsubishi eco x or such body kits would work effectively
Any tips in general would also be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I will let the Stack decide, however this question is pretty much a shopping question to me. It's borderline at best, thus why I'll leave it to the Stack.